# Do telegram chat IDs stay the same when converting to a supergroup?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

On Telegram, every group has a `chat-id` that my bot saves whenever it is added to a group.

If an owner of a group converts it to a supergroup, will the ID of the group change? And if it does, how can we get the new `chat-id` for the group?

---

> I've looked for this all over the internet without success, so I'm asking here to self-answer to help people looking for this in the future, saving them the time trial and error took me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing it out for myself, the `chat-id` **does change** on migration to a supergroup.

However I found the following way, using `python-telegram-bot` to keep your chat-ids updated:

```py
def migchat(bot, update):
  oldchatid = update.message.migrate_from_chat_id
  newchatid = update.message.chat.id
  # process those values as needed (e.g. update a database)

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.migrate, migchat))
```

This uses the [Filters submodule](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.status_update) to call `migchat` whenever a chat is being migrated.

This is how the JSON response of the message from the `/getUpdates` call looks like:
[image: API response]