# Can chat IDs of telegram bots be changed?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Can we change the chat ID of a telegram bot from `Telegram` to `ID CHAT` ?

I want to save more chat IDs in my database.

To extrapolate it, I use this method:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY_YY/getUpdates
```

Besides this, is every **chat ID** (for private chat, group and channel) is unique ?
I would to use it like a token.
Is a good idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Chat ID's of groups **does** change!

In my case it happened when the 26th member was added (2nd bot) and got admin rights.

`-4242ххххх` **id changed to** `-10013430ххххх`.

Group had no chat_photo and color of circle sign had been also changed.

Also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864930/do-telegram-chat-ids-stay-the-same-when-converting-to-a-supergroup) about migrate to supergroup and get old id.

Comment: In my case group chat id changed when I changed group settings

Answer (score 2):

Chat ID's of groups **could** change!

It could change if the chat is changed. For example if a group is upgraded to supergroup its chat id will get changed too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a group or channel on telegram, the chat_id does change. It usually changes if a member is promoted to admin or members are added in a group. However, there is no certain pattern.