# Telegram bot API is the chat_id unique for each user contacting the bot?

Tags: python, authentication, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

We are using python API for telegram bots and need to be able to identify the user.

Is the chat_id unique for each user connecting the bot?

Can we trust the chat_id to be consistent? e.g same chat_id will tell us that this is the same user, and each user connecting with the bot will have one chat_id that is consistent between sessions?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is the chat_id unique for each user connecting the bot?

*Yes*

`chat_id` will always be unique for each user connecting to your bot.
If the same user sends messages to different bots, they will always 'identify' themselves with their unique `id`.

Keep in mind that `getUpdates` shows the users id, and the id from the chat.

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "update_id": 1234567,
            "message": {
                "message_id": 751,
                "from": {
                    "id": 12122121,                     <-- user.id
                    "is_bot": false,
                    "first_name": "Me",
                    "last_name": "&",
                    "username": "&&&&",
                    "language_code": "en"
                },
                "chat": {
                    "id": -104235244275,                <-- chat_id
                    "title": "Some group",
                    "type": "supergroup"
                },
                "date": 1579999999,
                "text": "Hi!"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864930/do-telegram-chat-ids-stay-the-same-when-converting-to-a-supergroup), that `chat.id` will not change, even if the group is converted to a supergroup

Based on comment; small overvieuw of private/group chat example

```
user_1 ---> bot_a     in private chat
{
    "message": {
        "from": {
            "id": 12345678          <-- id from user_1
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": 12345678,         <-- send from private chat, so chat is equals to user_id
        }
    }
}

user_2 ---> bot_a     in private chat
{
    "message": {
        "from": {
            "id": 9876543          <-- id from user_2
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": 9876543,         <-- send from private chat, so chat is equals to user_id
        }
    }
}

user_1 ---> bot_a     in group chat
{
    "message": {
        "from": {
            "id": 12345678         <-- id from user_1
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": 5646464,         <-- send from group chat, so id is from groupchat
        }
    }
}

user_2 ---> bot_a     in group chat
{
    "message": {
        "from": {
            "id": 9876543          <-- id from user_2
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": 5646464,         <-- send from group chat, so id is from groupchat
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I have two bots, and the same user will talk to both of them, He/She will have two chat_id's or one?

Comment: Both the `chat_id` and `user_id` will be the same since you're sending the chat from the same user, and so the same (private) chat. If the first user would send a private message to the bot, and the second user will target the bot though a groupchat, then the (from) `user_id` will be the same. Except this time the (from) `chat_id` will be different, one id of the private chat, and the other id from the groupchat

Comment: I've added a small example @thebeancounter

Comment: can anyone help me in a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68815736/10302693

Comment: @0stone0 what if it's two different bots? will `from.id` be the same for the same user account in all groups and bot-direct messages (for bot_a and bot_b)?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answer (and addressing questions raised in the comments):

Yes, the `user_id` is the same across bots. Two bots communicating with the same user will receive the same `user_id`. However, `chat_ids` are (of course) different.

Source: I couldn't find clear information on the web and simply created two test bots.