# Why there are 2 different id's for one channel in telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Normally there is a negative `id` for each channel in telegram, but when you extract one channel's history, there exists a key in the returned json named as `from_id`. It is a positive number and it's unique. Meanwhile it belongs to the same channel. What is the difference between `from_id` and that negative id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `from_id` is from the user sending the message, that's problably a positive number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Telegram bot API is the chat\_id unique for each user contacting the bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748008/telegram-bot-api-is-the-chat-id-unique-for-each-user-contacting-the-bot)

Comment: @0stone0 That's what i thought first, but it's not. it's unique and it's the same number for all message senders. do it yourself, extract one channel's history and check this out.