# My telegram bot answers in personal chats but don't in group chats. Why?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

My telegram bot answers in personal chats but don't in group chats. I could not find the problem.
A snippet from my code:

```
@app.route('/{}'.format(TOKEN), methods=['POST'])
def respond():
    # retrieve the message in JSON and then transform it to Telegram object
    update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), bot)

    # get the chat_id to be able to respond to the same user
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id

    # Telegram understands UTF-8, so encode text for unicode compatibility
    text = update.message.text

    if text == '/start':
        response = send_welcome()
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=response)
    elif 'discord' in text.split():
        response = send_discord()
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=response)
    elif 'edeka' in text.split():
        response = send_edeka()
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=response)
    elif 'random' in text.split():
        response = send_random()
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=response)             
    elif 'metro' in text.split():
        response = send_metro()
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=response)
    elif text == '/help':
        response = send_help()
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=response) 
    elif text == 'Good bot':
        response = 'Önemli degil kanka'    
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=response)    

    return 'ok'
```

I get an error message in heroku for text.split(), but only from group chats.

Comment: Could you paste the error message?

Answer (score 1):

```py
# get the chat_id to be able to respond to the same user
chat_id = update.message.chat.id
```

This is from the person sending the message. Therefore, if a person targets your bot in a group chat, you'll reply to his personal id.

Consider using

```py
chat_id = update.message.from.id
```

This is the chat the message was send in, in this case it could be the group chat you want to reply to.

To get a better understanding about the different id's take a look at for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59750179/5625547)

Comment: Sorry, but what should I consider to use? Your answer is same with my code.

Comment: I'm sorry @canakkaleli, copy/paste mistake. I've fixed it. Take a look at the `chat` and `from` objects on the `message`!