# Can multiple telegram accounts have same ID?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am using this bot to get id by username: @get_any_telegram_id_bot

And for many accounts it returns same id. Is it by mistake?
It returns this id only for account which I would call "suspicious" - like black market and so on.

How can this be explained? Bot bug? Or it returns this id for accounts marked in some way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Telegram bot API is the chat\_id unique for each user contacting the bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748008/telegram-bot-api-is-the-chat-id-unique-for-each-user-contacting-the-bot)

Comment: Yoour probably looking at the bot id.

Answer (score 0):

user_id is supposed to be unique, and it's most likely the bot implementation cause.

How they even receive user ids is a big question; methods for that are a bit hacky. It could happen for instance, that the bot keeps a database of user ids fetched in some hacky way (ways), and returns some id because of some data corruption issue.

Of course, that all would be a guessing game until we see the bot's source code, which seems to be unavailable.